# Proving that if $A^n = 0$, then $I - A$ is invertible and $(I - A)^{-1} = I + A + \cdots + A^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ be a squared matrix, and suppose there exists an $n\in \Bbb N$ in a way that $A^n=0$. Show that $I-A$ is invertible and that $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+\cdots+A^{n-1}$

I don't have a clue where to start from.

Comment: related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336869/expanding-ia-1/

Comment: duplicate question

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: There are several related questions. Just google "nilpotent matrix invertible". (Note that $A^n = O$ for some $n$ is equivalent to $A$ being nilpotent.)

Comment: Of course this has nothing to do with matrices, it holds in every ring.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg my proof doesn't use matrices at all and juliens only a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you check a matrix $B$ is the inverse of matrix $A$? You multiply them together and see if you get the identity matrix. This is just the definition of inverse matrix.

You have a matrix $I-A$ and you want to check that its inverse is $1+A+A^2+...+A^{n-1}$ given that $A^n=0$.

So multiply together and after doing lots of cancellations etc you get $I - A^n = I$, which is what we were after!

Comment: that totally looks like juliens answer

Comment: I didn't read any of the answers a priori...I just typed my own. However now I have read his answer I feel that Julian's is a bit more technically phrased (the question does not need to go into the rank-nullity theorem and the abstractness of quasinilpotents in unitary Banach algebras, I doubt the person asking the question wants this either). I decided to take a down to earth approach by first explaining what we were trying to do in a simple manner. Of course the maths is the same but on a question like this surely 99% of answers will be! I guess it is up to the person asking the question...

Comment: I think my answer is very down to earth. I mentioned the rank-nullity theorem just because it is a good opportunity to recall that left invertible is enough with square matrices. (You omitted to mention that the product had to be $I$ in both directions). Then if you read, I mention that the two matrices commute, so it is not needed. And finally, I only mentioned quasinilpotents in comments. This being said, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Set $B:=I+A+\ldots+A^{n-1}$ and compute $(I-A)B$ by expanding the product:
$$
(I-A)B=(I-A)(I+A+\ldots+A^{n-1})=I+A+\ldots+A^{n-1}-A(I+A+\ldots+A^{n-1})
$$
$$
=I+A+\ldots+A^{n-1}-A-A^2-\ldots-A^{n-1}-A^n=\;?
$$

Observe the cancellations: you are left with $I$. This suffices to show that $I-A$ is invertible with inverse $B$. This is by the rank-nullity theorem: a square matrix is right invertible if and only if it is invertible. Or you can observe that $B$ and $I-A$ commute, so $(I-A)B=I$ yields also $B(I-A)=I$.

Comment: finally we got totally different ways :)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I actually refrained from doing the quasinilpotent generalization in a unital Banach algebra...That would have been closer to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Well wenn $A^n=0$ then we konw that every eigenvalue of $A$ is zero, taking jordannormalform one sees that $I-A$ is invertible cause it is similar to a triangular matrix with every value 1 on the diagonal.
Afterwards you make something like the geommetric series

$$\frac{1}{1-x}= 1+x+x^2+\dots$$
now we have matrices but it is essentially the same it give syou 
$$(I-A)^{-1}=1+ A +A^2 + \dots+ A^{n-1} + \underbrace{A^n}_{=0}+\dots$$
But as every $A^k$ for $k\geq n$ is zero it is finite.

As Git mentioned it is unneccessary to go to infty

We can even take the finite geometric series which says that 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} x^i = \frac{x^n -1}{x-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$

We have $$(I-A)^{-1}= (I-A^n) \cdot (I-A)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} A^i = I + A + A^2 + \dots + A^{n-1}$$

Comment: @GitGud added the finite way thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Under which conditions for the matrix $A$ is this formula $(I-A)^{-1} = I + A + A^2 + ...$ valid ?