# $I+B$ is invertible if $B^{k} = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

If $B$ is nilpotent and $B^{k} = 0$ (and B is square), how should I go around proving that $I + B $ is invertible? I tried searching for a formula - $I = (I + B^{k}) = (I + B)(???)$

But I didn't get anywhere :(

Comment: Expand $1/(I+B)$ using the formula for a geometric series.

Comment: $$I+B^k = (I+B)(I-B + B^2 - B^3 + \dots +(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1})$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352383/proving-that-if-an-0-then-i-a-is-invertible-and-i-a-1-i-a and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140348/prove-that-ai-is-invertible-if-a-is-nilpotent

Comment: @Crostul: $I+B^k$, or $I-B^k$?

Answer (score 8):

Heuristically, "expand"
\begin{align*}
\frac{I}{I+B}&=I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1}+(-1)^kB^k+\cdots\\
&=I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1}.
\end{align*}
To have a rigorous solution, verify directly that
$$
(I+B)(I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1})=I.
$$

Comment: This is not true for $(1+x^{4})$ which is not equal to $(1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3)$

Comment: @Lisa This answer doesn't claim that it is.  But $(1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3) = 1-x^4$.

Comment: So what does $(1+x^4)$ equal to?

Comment: @Lisa: $1+x^4 = (1-\sqrt{2}x+x^2)(1+\sqrt{2}+x^2)$.  But what is being used here is the idea that if $B^k = 0$, then obviously $I-B^k = I$.  But $I-B^k$ can be factored as $(I+B)(I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1})$.  Therefore $(I+B)(I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1}) = I$, and thus $(I+B)^{-1}$ exists and is equal to $I-B+B^2+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}B^{k-1}$.

Comment: @KimJongUn: I think it may be better to use $I$ in the numerator of your first fraction, perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

If $B$ is nilpotent then its only eigenvalue is $0$. You can see this by observing that if $(\lambda,x)$ is any eigenpair of $B$, then $0 = B^k x = \lambda^k x \implies \lambda^k = 0 \implies \lambda = 0$. Thus, $\lambda = 1$ is the only eigenvalue of $I + B$ and so $I + B$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially if $B$ is idempotent of order $n$ you can find a basis where

$$B=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & b_{12} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & b_{23} &  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 &  & 0\\
\vdots &  &  & \ddots & b_{n-1n}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

In this form you can easly see what's happening when you calculate $B^k$. For example squaring $B$ we get:
$$B^2=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 &0 & b_{12}b_{23} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 &0 & 0 & b_{23}b_{34} &  & 0\\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots &  \vdots \\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & \ddots &  b_{n-2n-1}b_{n-1n}\\
\vdots&\vdots &  &  & \ddots &0 \\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
Everytime you multiply for $B$ you shift the non zero columns and rows by one. You can fill out the details yourself, (for example treating the general case of $B$ idempotent of order k, doesn't change much) this was just to give you an useful picture of what's happening....
Clearly in this base
$$I+B=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & b_{12} & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & b_{23} &  & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &  & 0\\
\vdots &  &  & \ddots & b_{n-1n}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
and $det(I+B)=1$ and so it's clearly invertible.

In the general case you can always write $I+B$ as un upper triangular matrix with $1$ on the diagonal and so with $det(I+B)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Factor $I-B^k$ and $I-B$ is one factor, but it also equals $I$ since $B^k=0$.

Comment: +1.  A little terse, perhaps, but it doesn't deserve a downvote.  Maybe you should expand "it" as $I-B^k$?

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you Brian, I guess the complain of the downvoters is that I factored out $I-B$ and not $I+B$ but I meant it more as a hint than a complete answer.  Appreciate the upvote :-)

Comment: Ahh, yes, well, I would probably change that to $I+B$, myself.  Do as you will, of course.