# Proving $\|e^A\|\le e^{\|A\|}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I'm trying to prove this inequality:

> $\|e^A\|\le e^{\|A\|}$, where $A$ is a matrix and $\|A\|:=\sup_{|x|=1}
>  |Ax|$.

**My attempt of solution:**

Since $e^A:=I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots$

we have

$$\|e^A\|=\|I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots\|=\sup_{|x|=1}\|(I+A+A^2/2!+A^3/3!+\ldots)x\|$$

$$=\sup_{|x|}\|Ix+Ax+(A^2x)/2!+(A^3x)/3!+\ldots\| $$
$$\leq \sup_{|x|}\|Ix\| +\sup_{|x|=1}\|Ax\|+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^2x\|}{2!}+\frac{\sup_{|x|}\|A^3x\|}{3!}+\ldots$$

Am I right so far? I couldn't go further

I need help!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use the fact that $\|A+B\|\le \|A\|+\|B\|$.

Comment: That's true in any unital Banach algebra by triangular inequality and submultiplicativity of the norm.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325891/left-cdot-right-is-an-induced-norm-if-left-a-right-1-how/326098#326098) is the technique you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've established a few basic properties (subadditivity, submultiplicativity, and continuity) of the norm, you can do it without having to bring in the $\sup$ manipulation. Namely, for any $n$, we have by subadditivity of the norm that
$$
\| I+A+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\cdots +\frac{A^n}{n!} \| \leq \| I\| + \|A\|+\|\frac{A^2}{2!}\|+\cdots +\|\frac{A^n}{n!} \| 
$$
Then since we know $\| A^2\| \leq \| A\|^2$, we can pull all the exponents out:

$$
\| I\| + \|A\|+\|\frac{A^2}{2!}\|+\cdots +\|\frac{A^n}{n!} \|  \leq \| I\| + \|A\|+\frac{1}{2!} \|A\|^2 +\cdots +\frac{1}{n!} \|A \|^n 
$$
Then since the norm is a continuous function, we can actually pass onto the limit as $n\to \infty$ of the above inequality, and obtain
$$
\|e^A \| = \|I+A+\cdots \| \leq \| I\| + \|A\|+\frac{1}{2!} \|A\|^2 +\cdots +\frac{1}{n!} \|A \|^n + \cdots = e^{\| A\|}
$$

Comment: Ah, good point!

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much