# How to show that $I-T$ is surjective, if $\|T\|<1$?

Tags: normed-spaces

I got stuck on an exercise in page 258, *Real analysis*(4ed),H.L. Royden et al:

> Let $X$ be Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,X)$ have $\|T\|<1$. Show that $I-T$ is an isomorphism.

$\mathcal{L}(X,X)$ is the collection of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$. $I$ is the identity function. I know that since $T$ is contractive, $I-T$ must be one-to-one. $\|(I-T)(u)\|\leq(1+\|T\|)\|u\|$ and $\|(I-T)^{-1}(u)\|\leq\frac{1}{(1-\|T\|)}\|u\|$ together imply that $I-T$ and its inverse are both continuous. But I have no clue how to show that $I-T$ is surjective.

**Added**: Finally, with copious hints, I got it. Thank you again!

Comment: Well, $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists, so...

Comment: Try showing the infinite sum $1+T+T^2+T^3+\ldots$ converges.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you for your hint. Since it and its inverse are continuous, its domain should be clopen and unbounded. But how to proceed?

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace You seem to be missing the forest for the trees. Forget all the other details and think about what $I-T$ being invertible *means*.

Comment: Here is the [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325891/left-cdot-right-is-an-induced-norm-if-left-a-right-1-how/326098#326098) for the $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Do you know the definition for an operator to be surjective?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal:$(I-T)[X]=X$,right?

Comment: Use Jeff Tolliver's hint: show that $S = 1+T+T^2 + \cdots$ converges and verify that $(1-T)S = 1$ and $S(1-T) = 1$ (geometric series).

Comment: @Martin: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling the comments into an answer:

Since $\lVert T\rVert \lt 1$, the series $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$ converges because $\lVert S\rVert \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \lVert T\rVert^n = \frac{1}{1-\lVert T\rVert}$ shows its absolute convergence.

A direct computation (geometric series) shows that
$$
(1-T)S = (1-T)\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n = 1 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty T^n -\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^{n+1} = 1
$$
and similarly $S(1-T) = 1$. This implies that $(1-T)$ is invertible with inverse $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$, and it follows that $(1-T)$ is both injective and surjective.

Remark: The geometric series for operators is usually called the [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).