# $\left\| {\left| {BA - I} \right|} \right\| < 1$ $ \Rightarrow $ $A$ and $B$ are both nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {M_n}$ satisfy the inequality $\left\| {\left| {BA - I} \right|} \right\| < 1$ and $\left\| {\left| . \right|} \right\|$ be a matrix norm on ${M_n}$.Why do $A$ and $B$ are both nonsingular?

Comment: This almost answer your question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325891/left-cdot-right-is-an-induced-norm-if-left-a-right-1-how?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

$$BA = I + BA - I.$$
Let $Y = BA-I.$

$$

$$(I+Y)^{-1} = \sum Y^j$$

This converges by the assumption. So $BA$ is invertible. So $A$ and $B$ are.