# Inverse of matrix sum, special case: $(A + x I)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Is there a simple way to do $(A + x I)^{-1}$ where $A$ is an invertible matrix, $I$ is unit matrix and $x$ is a scalar?

I see a lot of expressions for the general case $(A + B)^{-1}$, but nothing on the special case where $B = x I$.

I have to do $(A + x I)^{-1}$ for many $x$ values, so I want to know if some identity can be applied. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you apply the expressions for the general case to the special case?

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Thanks for editing. In general cases with varying $B$, I still need to do $B^{-1}$ in every iteration. I believe that the fact that $B$ is diagonal might lead to some simplifications.

Comment: $(xI)^{-1}$ should simplify nicely

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291102/matrix-proof-using-norms/291200#291200).

Answer (score 2):

For the similar expression $(I+xA)^{-1}$ we can use
$$ (I+xA)^{-1}=I+xA+x^2A^2+x^3A^3+\ldots$$
provided $x^nA^n\to 0$ (for example if $A$ is nilpotent).
Note that $A+xI = x\cdot(\frac1xA+I)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Perhaps the r.h.s. is $I + \sum_{i=1} ^\infty (-1)^i x^i A^i$