# $\lVert A\lVert<1$ implies $1-A$ invertible only true in complete spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

It is a well known fact that

> if in a Banach space $X$ a bounded linear operator $A:X\to X$ satisfies $\lVert A\lVert<1$, then $1-A$ has a bounded inverse.

I was wondering wether completeness is actually a necessary condition. I *think* the following argument is corect and doesn't use completeness:

Clearly for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$ $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^N A^k\right)(1-A)=1-A^{N+1}.$$ 
Since $\lVert A^{N+1}-0\lVert\leq\lVert A\lVert^{N+1}\rightarrow 0$ the limit of the right hand side exists and equals $1$. Hence also $$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^N A^k\right)(1-A)=1$$ and therefore $(1-A)^{-1}=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=0}^N A^k$. To see that the inverse is bounded I note that by continuity of the norm $$\lVert(1-A)^{-1}\lVert=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left\lVert \sum_{k=0}^NA^k\right\lVert\leq\sum_{k=0}^N \lVert{A}\lVert^k=\frac{1}{1-\lVert A\lVert}<\infty.$$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291102/matrix-proof-using-norms/291200#291200).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without some completeness hypothesis, the infinite sum expressing the inverse may not converge in the given space.

Comment: But I showed that the right hand side of the equality converges in $B(X)$. Isn't that sufficient to know that the left hand side also converges?

Comment: @Julian: Of course the left hand side converges to $1$, but so what? What you need is for the infinite sum to converge, which is another matter.

Comment: But if $a_n b$ converges for some $b\not=0$ independent of $n$ then also $a_n$ converges, isn't it?

Comment: Oh that's where my mistake was... the above statement isn't true..